zipfile.extractall does not work within watchdog filesystemeventhandler class
I am building a script that watches an inbox for a file to be created and then processes it. My end user wants to use zip files so I'm currently building that functionality into the Jupyter Notebook.
When the inbox is empty and I upload a 'test.zip' file into it, the handler class sees the zip file and prints that its file path is inbox/test.zip (as expected). Within the on_created method, the if statement returns True for the path ending in zip so the file should be unzipped and files get extracted. Except I keep get a 'BadZipFile' error.
class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    
    def on_created(self, event):
        print(event.src_path)
        def extract_zip(zip_filename, extract_to_directory):
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, 'r') as zip_ref:
                zip_ref.extractall(extract_to_directory)

        UNRED_DIR = r'outbox/unredacted'
        RED_DIR   = r'outbox/redacted'
        ERR_DIR = r'outbox/error/'
        FY = '25'
        
        if event.src_path.lower().endswith('.zip'):
            
            INBOX_DIR = r'extracted_files'
            
            print('Unzipping {}...'.format(event.src_path))
            extract_to_directory = 'extracted_files'
            extract_zip(event.src_path, extract_to_directory)
            print('Files extracted...')
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(extract_to_directory):
                print(root,dirs,files)
                for filename in files:
                    print('Working on {}...'.format(filename))
                    manage_and_redact_files(filename, INBOX_DIR, UNRED_DIR, RED_DIR, ERR_DIR, FY)

        
def observe():
    folder_to_watch = r'inbox'
    event_handler = Handler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_to_watch, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()

What really throws me off is that if I try uploading the 'test.zip' file again (the key piece of information here is that the file already exists in the inbox, so Jupyter asks me if I want to overwrite it and I say yes) the handler prints a file path of inbox/~.test.zip and now the zip file is handled just fine, the extract method extracts the files, they are managed appropriately by other functions, and all the code works.
I can't for the life of me figure out uploading a zip file generates a bad zip file error, but overwriting a zip file has everything run smooth. TIA.
